# Android Service did not stop

Tags: android, service, kill, destroy

I have a main class with two buttons to start and stop the service.

```
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
        myService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(myService);
        break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
        stopService(myService);
        break;
    }
}
```

Start Service intended to send current GPS coordinates to the server. it starts perfectely but did not stop on button click.

In MYService.java i have this code onDestroy method.

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

Please help how to kill this Service.

Comment: Check if "onClick: stopping srvice" appears in the log when you click the button. It might be something silly, like a typo in the button id, and `stopService()` never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

try this for stop services `stopService(itnt_BackServices );` in this example `itnt_BackServices` is name of services. you cant stop services in services class but stop in any activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.startId = startId;
    return mStartMode;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopSelf(startId);
}
```

Comment: My onStop never stop my background service, have tried many solution but no luck please suggest any idea .